# IISConfig.exe arguments for custom action in Microsoft Release Management

Tags: iis, deployment, release-management, ms-release-management

after creating an application pool in IIS(8.0) using Release Management 2013 Update 4, I need to customize the predefined action.
I would like to set *Load User Profile* in the advanced application pool settings true instead of false. I assumed I could use -loadUserProfile as an argument in Release Management.
Apparently the arguments are not similar to the parameter names in IIS. The release was rejected and the log file showed: *ERROR: loaduserprofile : Unknown Option*.
Release Management is using IISConfig.exe to execute the arguments. Even knowing that, I was unable to find a list of arguments or "Options" which can be used for the IISConfig.exe.
I would be glad to know how to solve that Problem. Not only in that specific case but in general.

Answer (score 0):

Find the details of the IIS tool here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/overview

Scroll to IIS Deployment Agent.

There does not seem to be any way to change the Load User Profile. You can write your own tool to accomplish that (and share it here :))